# data.table not recognising logical in filter

Tags: r, data.table

in the following snippet, data.table does not seem to recognize logicals when used in i.

All my attempts to reproduce the problem in a minimal example failed, that's why I am posting the complete section here. I expect it to be related to the part  "as.logical(cumsum(CURRENT_TRIP))", but just a gut feeling...

```
# Testdata
timetable <- data.table(rbind(
    c("r1", "t1_1", "p1", 10, 10),
    c("r1", "t1_1", "p2", 11, 11),
    c("r1", "t1_1", "p3", 12, 12),
    c("r1", "t1_1", "p4", 13, 13),
    c("r1", "t1_1", "p5", 14, 14),
    c("r1", "t1_1", "p6", 15, 15),
    c("r1", "t1_1", "p7", 16, 16),
    c("r1", "t1_1", "p8", 17, 17),
    c("r1", "t1_1", "p9", 18, 18),
    c("r1", "t1_1", "p10", 19, 19),

    c("r2", "t2", "p11", 9, 9),
    c("r2", "t2", "p12", 10, 10),
    c("r2", "t2", "p3", 11, 11),
    c("r2", "t2", "p13", 12, 12),
    c("r2", "t2", "p14", 13, 13),
    c("r2", "t2", "p15", 14, 14),
    c("r2", "t2", "p16", 15, 15),
    c("r2", "t2", "p17", 16, 16),
    c("r2", "t2", "p18", 17, 17)
  ))
setnames(timetable, c("ROUTE", "TRIP", "STOP", "ARRIVAL", "DEPARTURE"))
timetable[, ':='(ARRIVAL = as.integer(ARRIVAL), DEPARTURE = as.integer(DEPARTURE))]


# Input
startStation <- "p3"
startTime <- 8

setorder(timetable, TRIP, ARRIVAL)
timetable[, ID := .I]

timetable[,':='(ARR_ROUND_PREV = Inf, ARR_ROUND = Inf, ARR_BEST = Inf, MARKED = F, CURRENT_TRIP = F)]
timetable[STOP == startStation, ':='(ARR_ROUND_PREV = startTime, ARR_ROUND = startTime, ARR_BEST = startTime, MARKED = T)]

routes <- timetable[MARKED == T, unique(ROUTE)] 
ids <- timetable[MARKED == T & DEPARTURE > ARR_ROUND, .(ID = ID[DEPARTURE == min(DEPARTURE)]), by = ROUTE][, ID]

timetable[ID %in% ids, CURRENT_TRIP := T]
timetable[, MARKED := F]

trips <- timetable[CURRENT_TRIP == T, unique(TRIP)]
timetable[TRIP %in% trips, CURRENT_TRIP := as.logical(cumsum(CURRENT_TRIP)), by = TRIP]

# ?
timetable
nrow(timetable[CURRENT_TRIP == T]) #8
sum(timetable$CURRENT_TRIP == T) #15

# but 
nrow(timetable[CURRENT_TRIP > 0]) #15
nrow(timetable[CURRENT_TRIP == 1L]) #15
```

any ideas?

Problem shows up using newest 1.9.7 and 1.9.6 and R 3.2.3 on Win 64bit

Fab

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. You can set `options(datatable.auto.index = FALSE)` or use `nrow(timetable[(CURRENT_TRIP == T)])`. Btw, your way of creating the initial data.table is stupid. Don't use `rbind`/`cbind` for this.

Comment: Besides the construction of your data.table, you are using `':='` instead of ``` around the `:=`. Furthermore: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you point out where you do have a problem? `as.logical(cumsum(CURRENT_TRIP))` is working as expected (using data.table 1.9.7 & R 3.2.2 on OSX).

Comment: @Jaap The problem is the result of `nrow(timetable[CURRENT_TRIP == T])`, which should be 15, not 8. (But I admit, the example is reproducible, but far from minimal.)

Comment: @Roland that is indeed strange

Comment: @Roland 1. it is difficult to come up with a minimal example without knowing where the problem comes from. My attempts failed. Do you have a hint are proposal for a minimal example? I could then post it as data.table issue. 2. Why does using an additional pair of brackets help? 3. I know there are better ways to fill a table with sample data. But the used one is the only one I'm aware of, that adds data "rowwise". Colwise data adding makes things less clear, I think. What ways of table initialization are you proposing? Thanks fab

Comment: @FabianGehring Minimal reproducible example added to data.table forum [link](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1479)

Answer (score 2):

You have exactly the same bug that I have!!!

[Strange issue with data.table row search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353464/strange-issue-with-data-table-row-search)

I also could not reproduce it with a minimal code!

My solution to your code is changing how you set the column CURRENT_TRIP.

```
timetable[ID %in% ids]$CURRENT_TRIP <- T
timetable[, MARKED := F]

trips <- timetable[CURRENT_TRIP == T, unique(TRIP)]
timetable[TRIP %in% trips]$CURRENT_TRIP <- timetable[,as.logical(cumsum(CURRENT_TRIP)), by = TRIP]$V1

# ?
timetable
nrow(timetable[CURRENT_TRIP == T]) #8
sum(timetable$CURRENT_TRIP == T) #15

# but 
nrow(timetable[CURRENT_TRIP > 0]) #15
nrow(timetable[CURRENT_TRIP == 1L]) #15
```

Using the dT[,Column:=T] notation for setting up columns also caused me the same issue! I am not sure why and I am in touch with the creator of data.tables to fix this!

Comment: Also to add this has been tested on the latest data.table stable release (1.9.6) as we speak and R 3.2.2 on Mac OSX. Both the bugged code and the fix behaved as expected.

Comment: hi, bug was reported and accepted by the package developers. See here for updates: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1479

Comment: Thank you! This is nice!