# Strange issue with data.table row search

Tags: r, data.table

I am a big fan and massive user of data.tables in R. I really use them for a lot of code but have recently encountered a strange bug:

I have a huge data.table with multiple columns, example:

```
   x y
1: 1 a
2: 1 b
3: 1 c
4: 2 a
5: 2 b
6: 2 c
7: 3 a
8: 3 b
9: 3 c
```

if I select

```
dataDT[x==‘1’]
```

I end up getting

```
   x y
1: 1 a
```

whereas

```
dataDT[(x==‘1’)]
```

gives me

```
   x y
1: 1 a
2: 1 b
3: 1 c
```

Any ideas? x and y are factor and the data.table is indexed by `setKey` by `x`.

ADDITIONAL INFOS AND CODE:

I actually fixed this issue but in a way that is not clear nor intuitive.

My code is structured as follows: I have a function called from my main code where I have to introduce a column in the data.table.

I have previously used the following notation

dataT[,nC:=oC,]

to do the deed.

I have instead found that creating the new column by using

dataT$nC <- dataT$oC

instead fixes the bug completely.

I tried to replicate the exact same bug on a simpler example code but I cannot, possibly because of dependencies related to the size structure of my data.table as well as the specific functions I am running on my table.

With that said, I have a working example that shows that when you insert a column using the dataT[,nC:=oC,] notation, it acts as if the table were passed by reference to the function rather than by value.

Also, interestingly enough, while performing

dataDT[x==‘1’]

vs

dataDT[(x==‘1’)]

shows the same result, the latter is 10 times slower, which I have noticed previously. I hope this code can shed some light.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(data.table)


superParF <- function(dtInput){

  dtInputP <- dtInput[a==1]
  dtInputN <- dtInput[a==2]

  outDT    <- rbind(dtInputP[,sum(y),by='x'],
                    dtInputN[,sum(y),by='x'])
  return(outDT)
}

superFunction <- function(dtInput){

  #create new column
  dtInput[,z:=y,]

  #run function
  outDT <- rbindlist(lapply(unique(inputDT$x),
                        function(i)
                          superParF(inputDT[x==i])))
  #output outDT
  return(outDT)
}




inputDT <- data.table(x = c(rep(1,100000),
                        rep(2,100000),
                        rep(3,100000),
                        rep(4,100000),
                        rep(5,100000)),
                  y= c(rep(1:100000,5)))

inputDT$x <-  as.factor(inputDT$x)
inputDT$y <- as.numeric(inputDT$y)

inputDT   <- rbind(inputDT,inputDT)
inputDT$a <- c(rep(1,500000),rep(2,500000))

setkey(inputDT,x)

#first observation-> the two searches do not work with the same performance

a <- system.time(inputDT[x=='1'])
b <- system.time(inputDT[(x=='1')])

print(a)
print(b)

out <- superFunction(inputDT)

a <- system.time(inputDT[x=='1'])
b <- system.time(inputDT[(x=='1')])

print(a)
print(b)

inputDT
```

Comment: Doesn't look like a data.table. Also, `‘1’` looks strange. I didn't yet edited, but I suspect it is because of your editor.

Comment: yes it is just my editor, I am not sure who to improve it. More than happy to take any edits to make it look better =) Thanks!

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. The `()`'s make no difference to me. Also, use `'quotedtext'` not `‘quotedtext’` in your code - otherwise it will not be running at all.

Comment: I can't replicate either.  Which is why we ask for version number and reproducible code.  Please read: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support.  e.g. top mistakes 2 and 3

Comment: Hi all, it's complicated because this is a huge table with 154826880 rows. Basically this is what I am doing:

1) I pass this table in input to a set of functions which manipulate the table internally but I do not save anything on it

2) If I perform this search before the function, the two look identical, whereas it's otherwise different.

3) dataDT[(x==1)] is approximately 10 times slower than dataDT[x==1] so I suspect it may have something to do with indexing

Comment: @nbafrank - the devil is in the detail, as they say. If you can boil your problem down to a specific piece of code that we can replicate an issue with, then it can be potentially solved. As it is, we're all guessing. My guess is that somehow your two pieces of code are returning 1) a single row index, like `1` vs 2) a logical selection like `x==1` returning `TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE....`

Comment: I will try to distill it and send out some example. Thanks! I wanted to send it out cuz 1) I was quite surprised and 2) I thought I missed something obvious and it is clearly not the case.

Comment: Version number of data.table please; i.e. paste the output of `sessionInfo()`. Please.

Answer (score 3):

I asked in comments to provide the version number and to follow the guidelines on the [Support](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support) page.  It contains :

> Read and search the README.md. Is there a bug fix or a new feature related to your issue? Probably we were aware of the issue or someone else reported it and we have already fixed the issue in the current development version.

So, searching the README.md for the string "index" just using Ctrl-F in the browser, yields :

> 21  Auto indexing handles logical subset of factor column using numeric value properly, #1361. Thanks @mplatzer.
>
> 26 Auto indexing returns order of subset properly when input data.table is already sorted, #1495. Thanks @huashan for the nice
>   reproducible example.

Those are fixed in v1.9.7 easily installed with one command detailed on the [Installation](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) page.

The first one (item 21) looks suspiciously close to your issue. So please do try v1.9.7 as requested on the Support page in point 4.

We ask for you state the version number up front to save time because we want to ensure you are using at least v1.9.6 on CRAN and not v1.9.4 which had this problem :

> DT[column == value] no longer recycles value except in the length 1 case (when it still uses DT's key or an automatic secondary key, as introduced in v1.9.4). If length(value)==length(column) then it works element-wise as standard in R. Otherwise, a length error is issued to avoid common user errors. DT[column %in% values] still uses DT's key (or an an automatic secondary key) as before. Automatic indexing (i.e., optimization of == and %in%) may still be turned off with options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE).

So which version are you running please and have you tried v1.9.7 since it looks like it's worth a try?

Comment: Hi Matt!

First of all thanks for your help! I am running version 1.9.6. I have not tried 1.9.7 yet, I realized it's a GitHub version. I will try it right now and let you know as soon as I can if I see this issue again.

Comment: Nope, did not solve it. I will generate a smaller contained example code for you to test.

Comment: @nbafrank Ok yes that's needed please.  On the off chance you're on Windows: you need to close all your R sessions and start a fresh session as Windows sometimes keeps old dll hanging around.  (Which is one reason we ask for `sessionInfo()` to avoid wasting time.)

Comment: @nbafrank Just to add ... it looks like a serious and annoying problem so thanks in advance for helping us find and fix it.

Comment: I have updated the question. I fixed the bug but I am not sure how it was actually fixed. Basically in one function I had to create a new column and I used the dataT[,nC:=oC,] notation. I found that switching to dataT$nC <- dataT$oC fixes the bug. The code I have attached shows unexpected behavior (on my part) of dataT[,nC:=oC,] and also the difference in time when selecting rows using dataT[x=='1'] vs dataT[(x=='1')] (the latter being slower and not affected by my bug).

Answer (score 1):

Using the dT[,Column:=Value] notation seems to cause the SAME BUG in another post as well!

[data.table not recognising logical in filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433063/data-table-not-recognising-logical-in-filter/35384971#35384971)

Replacing dT[,Column:=Value] with dT$Column <- Value fixes both my bug and this posts bug.

@Matt Dowle: this post that I am linking has much more succinct code that I have and the bug is the same! You would find it of great help in your quest to fix this issue!

Comment: I found out that this is actually one bug that the Data.Table team is working on https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1479

my solution can provide q temporary workaround to it.

Thanks!